# Connect esp8266 with AWS IOT

Tags: aws-iot, arduino-esp8266

I am using https://github.com/Schm1tz1/aws-sdk-arduino-esp8266 default repository inside arduino sdk.

But It's sample code wont update shadow thing on AWS IOT. I configured everything correctly, Can some one help me on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to develop code using ARDUINO IDE that connects ESP8266 with AWS IOT by using this repo:http://github.com/odelot/aws-mqtt-websockets

Answer (score 3):

I have put quite some time on this last month. All the examples I had found had an issue or another. It must be because library Core ESP8266 for Arduino has been updated not long ago; SSL implementation has changed...

I have been to figure out what was wrong, fix it, and make it work. I use the ESP8266 and connect to AWS IoT using MQTT and x509 certificate for authentication.

Here is the walkthrough I have put together: https://raphberube.com/blog/2019/02/18/Making-the-ESP8266-work-with-AWS-IoT.html

If you stumble on this I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: given walkthrough link is not working, please update it.

Comment: https://raphberube.com/making-the-esp-8266-work-with-aws-io-t

Answer (score 1):

The project mentioned by @Harshil Makwana forces you to create an IAM user and then put the credentials on the device. This is not a secure way to connect and should be avoided if possible.

The proper way is to use TLS 1.2, with the use of embedded certificates. A project showing how to do this can be found here: https://github.com/copercini/esp8266-aws_iot

Comment: That's nonsense. The IAM user method is as secure as the certificate one. You have to store the private credentails anyway so both provide the same level of security

Comment: I agree w/ Gianluca. Putting a certificate on a device doesn't it insecure given that proper IAM permissions are in place. Plus, an account admin can revoke that certificate at any moment if a device is compromised.